# Array "pointer" on writing the value?

Tags: c

I'm try to get from the user 5 strings, and store that string into a array of char string, but, when I try to use the program, the output of the program is allways the same, the last value of user have inputed...

See my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char *s[50];
    char str[50];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        fgets(str, 50, stdin);
        s[i] = str;
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%s\n ", s[i]);
}
```

So, How I can solve this, how I can put the value digited by the user into array, and print the values in other time ???

Comment: use strcpy(s[i], str) instead of s[i]=str

Comment: Using strcpy with the arguments `s` and `str` is incorrect; you don't want to copy a set of characters into a pointer array.

Comment: @ChristopherBales: you can't use `strcpy()` unless there's space to copy into...and you didn't make sure that such space was provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use strcpy instead of simple assignment.

str is a memory location, all s[i] = str is doing is pointing to the same buffer that is overwritten every time you call fgets.

Something like the following will get you what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char s[5][50];
    char str[50];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        fgets(str, 50, stdin);
        strcpy(s[i],str);
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%s\n ", s[i]);
}
```

Comment: At this point `str` and `strcpy` are doing you no good; you might as well just `fgets(s[i], 50, stdin)`.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a single array of characters with the following line

```
char str[50];
```

And then every pointer in your array `s` is pointing to that same single memory location. Everytime you call fgets, you're overwriting the string that is stored in that memory, and as such when you print out each of the strings in the `s` array, you're getting the same thing: the last value the user entered, which is stored in that single locally allocated block of memory.

Try allocating a new block of memory for each string you read in from the user, and then storing the new memory block's pointer in `s`:

```
char *str;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  str = malloc(50);
  fgets(str,50,stdin);
  s[i] = str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the pointers of `s` point to `str`. So only the last input is stored.

Do:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    fgets(str, 50, stdin);
    s[i] = strdup(str);
}
```

If strdup() is not available (POSIX function) then you can implement it or use `malloc()` + `strcpy()`.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    fgets(str, 50, stdin);
    s[i] = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(s[i], str);
}
```

And finally free() the pointers in `s`:

```
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {  
     free(s[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay :X... so, have an way to make this, whiout use strdup ou strcopy or malloc ???

Comment: No. There's no other way if you want to dynamically allocate strings. However, you can simply declare a static array. See here: http://ideone.com/8nRrvp

Answer (score 0):

Note that `char *s[50]` only declares 50 pointers (not pointers to 50 characters!); they need to point somewhere before you can copy something to them. What about a 2-dim array of char:

```
char s[5][50];
```

and then reading into them with

```
fgets (s[i], 50, stdin);
```

Advantage: No need to mess with strdup, malloc and free.